# Matlab Regress "Stats"

Tags: matlab, regression, multivariate-testing

Using MATLAB's' regress function like so:

```
[b,bint,r,rint,stats] = regress(responses,predictors_data);
stats
```

It runs fine, but using stats to get the r^2, Fstat, P-value, estimate of error variance.

My question is, how do I get the Fcrit value as well, to make the Fstat value have some meaning? Isn't the whole point of the Fstat to compare it to the Fcrit value?

Documentation: https://au.mathworks.com/help/stats/regress.html#d126e916077

Comment: I think the "default" value is 0.05... but I thought Fcrit was data dependent.